# Does the image in a LinearLayout must be the same size?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, imagebutton

i have wrote a program to test the MediaPlayer class, and it has three ImageButtons——"play","pause" and "stop". at the beginning, i uses three different size .png pictures for the three ImageButtons, and the program cannot be run on my AVD, and then i changed them to three .png picutres that have the same size, then it runs correctly this time.

does the image uses in a LinearLayout must be the same size??

here is the latyout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/play">
        </ImageButton>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/pause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/pause">
        </ImageButton>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/stop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/stop">
        </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is there a reason why you're using android:src instead of android:background?

Comment: but it is not the attributes' problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code it is fine but problem was in images you remove .png in your image it will work. Cool because .png is already in image and you also add .png in images so that remove .png from image.

Comment: you mean than they are already coded in PNG format, and don't need to name them to be .png explicitly???   but the goodones.zip are also named .png

Comment: I think problem is not in images goodones.zip if u use window go to folder option and check hide potion so that u can see differnece.

Comment: i did not select the option, so my images are all named like xxx.png

Comment: ok have solve probelm or still have .have u run project in emulator now or not ...cool

Answer (score 0):

> does the image uses in a LinearLayout must be the same size??

No. The wrap_content parameter will make the encapsulating LinearLayout only as big as the the largest ImageButton.

The problem may lie with the names of the drawables. Make sure your all your .png images follow android naming conventions (names can contain only lower case letters, the numbers 0-9, or an underscore).

Also check the images themselves aren't corrupt.

Comment: is there any tools to check whether the image could be used in an android program??? i get one of the .png image form a .jpg image, what i have done is just modified the type suffix of the .jpg to .png